# $\int_{0}^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{x} dx$ Integration help!

Tags: calculus, integration

$\int_{0}^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{x} dx$

Substituting $-x$ as $u$,

$\int_{0}^\infty \frac{e^u}{-u} du$

$\int_{0}^\infty \frac{1}{-u} e^u du$

$\int_{0}^\infty \frac{1}{-u} (\frac{u^0}{0!} + \frac{u^1}{1!} + \frac{u^2}{2!} + \frac{u^3}{3!} + ...) du$

$\int_{0}^\infty \frac{-1}{u} (1 + u + \frac{u^2}{2!} + \frac{u^3}{3!} + ...) du$

$\int_{0}^\infty (\frac{-1}{u} + \frac{-u}{u} - \frac{u}{2!} - \frac{u^2}{3!} - ...) du$

$\int_{0}^\infty (-1 - \frac{1}{u} - \frac{u}{2!} - \frac{u^2}{3!} - ...) du$

I don't know how to proceed further. Can someone help me finish this please?

Comment: The value of the integral is $\infty$.

Comment: You have the following for $z>0$: $$
\int_z^{ + \infty } {\frac{{e^{ - x} }}{x}dx}  =  - \log z - \gamma  + z - \frac{{z^2 }}{4} + \frac{{z^3 }}{{18}} -  \cdots 
$$ where $\gamma=0.5772\ldots$ is the Euler–Mascheroni constant. You can see that this blows up as $z\to 0$ because of the logarithmic term.

Comment: You can also regularize the integral via $$I(\epsilon)=\int_0^\infty x^{\epsilon-1}e^{-x}dx=\Gamma(\epsilon)=\frac{1}{\epsilon}\Gamma(1+\epsilon)=\frac{1}{\epsilon}\Big(1-\gamma\epsilon+\big(\gamma^2+\frac{\pi^2}{6}\big)\frac{\epsilon^2}{2}+O(\epsilon^3)\Big)$$
The higher derivatives of $\Gamma(1)$ can be found, for example, here https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228557691_Evaluation_of_higher-order_derivatives_of_the_Gamma_function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Near $0$, you have
$$\frac{e^{-x}}{x} \sim \frac{1}{x}$$

which is not integrable, so
$$\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-x}}{x}  dx = +\infty$$